# Even Function Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i have this code but i am not sure what i have done wrong. Once i type my number into the text box and i click calculate nothing happens.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Week 3 - Exercise 3-3</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function evenTest(num1) {   //function receives one parameter
            var num=num1;           //create and assign variable to number passed

            (num % 2==0) ? akert("Number is even"):alert("Number is odd");
            if (num>20) {
                    alert("Number is > 20");
            }
            else    {
                    alert("Number is not greater than 20");
                                                //message if <=20
            }                                   //end else
        }                                       //end function
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Exerise 3-3 - Even Function</h1>
    <form name="form1">
        Enter a number:<input name="firstNum" type="text"/><br/>
        <input type="button" value ="Calculate" onclick=evenTest(form1.firstNum.value)/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: there is a lot going wrong in that code, before anyone answers, do you see any developer tools console errors?

Comment: your code contains one obvious syntax error

Comment: You have a misspelling error: 'akert' instead of 'alert'. Please use some browser developer tool (press F12 in a browser) and check for this type of errors before posting a question.

Comment: Jaromanda it says Uncaught syntax error: unexpected token } in line 24. But there is no } there.

Comment: I fixed the spelling error. Still not working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wd1ejf9o/1/

Comment: Thankyou very much Arun for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Week 3 - Exercise 3-3</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function evenTest(num1) {   //function receives one parameter
            var num=num1;           //create and assign variable to number passed

            (num % 2==0) ? alert("Number is even"):alert("Number is odd");
            if (num>20) {
                    alert("Number is > 20");
            }
            else    {
                    alert("Number is not greater than 20");
                                                //message if <=20
            }                                   //end else
        }                                       //end function
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Exerise 3-3 - Even Function</h1>
    <form name="form1">
        Enter a number:<input name="firstNum" type="text"/><br/>
        <input type="button" value ="Calculate" onclick="evenTest(form1.firstNum.value)"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

- Your onclick wasn't in quotes
- you mistyped alert as akert

personally I would not rely on `form1` being a global variable either - but the above code works as intended

Comment: Why do I see "Uncaught ReferenceError: evenTest is not defined" when I run this code in jsfiddle.This is fiddle link 
https://jsfiddle.net/pxgjj8qL/

Comment: because you've split up the code and html on jsfiddle - change js to be `nowrap in head` or `nowrap in body` and it miraculously works like I said it did

Answer (score 0):

This is because of syntax error/typo in your code and html

**JS**

make

```
akert("Number is even")
```

To

```
alert("Number is even")
```

So the js function will be

```
    function evenTest(num1) {   //function receives one parameter
        var num=num1;           //create and assign variable to number passed

        (num % 2==0) ? alert("Number is even"):alert("Number is odd");
        if (num>20) {
                alert("Number is > 20");
        }
        else    {
                alert("Number is not greater than 20");
                                            //message if <=20
        }                                   //end else
    }                                       //end function
```

**and HTML will be**

//put the function call in quotation

```
<input type="button" value ="Calculate"onclick="evenTest(form1.firstNum.value)"/>
```

Comment: answers should answer the question, not just pick out one of a multitude of problems - and it's probasbly a typo

Answer (score 0):

This code may be useful

HTML Changes

```
<h1>Exerise 3-3 - Even Function</h1>
    <form name="form1">
        Enter a number:<input name="firstNum" id='ipV' type="text"/><br/>
        <input type="button" value ="Calculate" id="calB"/>
    </form>
```

JS Changes

```
 var x= document.getElementById('calB');
        x.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var _getNumber = document.getElementById('ipV').value
        evenTest(_getNumber);

    })
    function evenTest(num1) {   //function receives one parameter
       var num=num1;           //create and assign variable to number passed
           (num % 2==0) ? alert("Number is even"):alert("Number is odd");
                if (num>20) {
                        alert("Number is > 20");
                }
                else{
                   alert("Number is not greater than 20");
                }                                   
            }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tbe6zewg/5/)

Comment: why does your code alert without clicking the button?